# Get selected column from GTK# NodeView

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm writing some C# code on a Raspberry Pi using MonoDevelop.  I've got a `NodeView` widget that contains three columns.  I'd like to detect the column that was clicked in the NodeView.  I've tried to use `NodeSelection.Changed`, but, that does not tell me the column.  I've also tried coding a `ButtonPress` event for the NodeView and drilling down to the `TreePath`.  I got nowhere with that.

I've noticed this question asked several times.  But, I haven't seen a straight forward wy to get the row/column for a selected item in a `NodeView`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. This was a pain because, like you said, there is zero documentation on this.

So, to outline what I did, here is what my window looks like:
[image: program]

When I click on different columns, this is the output:

```
Clicked on column index 3 with title "hello 3"
Node selected: Prop1 29478338;Prop2 55998661;Prop3 1058200043;Prop4 1429485106
Clicked on column index 2 with title "hello 2"
Node selected: Prop1 1781730137;Prop2 618078535;Prop3 1253079243;Prop4 1149116957
Clicked on column index 1 with title "hello 1"
Node selected: Prop1 1577113328;Prop2 1907291485;Prop3 764000225;Prop4 1871218984
Clicked on column index 0 with title "hello 0"
Node selected: Prop1 1267506574;Prop2 692394441;Prop3 1291543143;Prop4 41456018
Clicked on column index 1 with title "hello 1"
Node selected: Prop1 1659363497;Prop2 873230641;Prop3 1799765877;Prop4 83248840
Clicked on column index 2 with title "hello 2"
Node selected: Prop1 1882743696;Prop2 419098689;Prop3 554049937;Prop4 671882960
```

And the code, as "not pretty" as it is (just quickly throwing stuff up to get it to work):

```
Random r = new Random();

[Gtk.TreeNode(ListOnly = true)]
public class MyTreeNode : Gtk.TreeNode
{
    public MyTreeNode(Random r)
    {
        AnotherProp1 = $"Prop1 {r.Next()}";
        AnotherProp2 = $"Prop2 {r.Next()}";
        AnotherProp3 = $"Prop3 {r.Next()}";
        AnotherProp4 = $"Prop4 {r.Next()}";
    }

    [Gtk.TreeNodeValue(Column = 0)]
    public string AnotherProp1 { get; private set; }

    [Gtk.TreeNodeValue(Column = 1)]
    public string AnotherProp2 { get; private set; }

    [Gtk.TreeNodeValue(Column = 2)]
    public string AnotherProp3 { get; private set; }

    [Gtk.TreeNodeValue(Column = 3)]
    public string AnotherProp4 { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString() =>
        $"{AnotherProp1};{AnotherProp2};{AnotherProp3};{AnotherProp4}";
}

private readonly NodeStore _store = new NodeStore(typeof(MyTreeNode));

public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build();

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        _store.AddNode(new MyTreeNode(r));
    }
    nodeview2.NodeStore = _store;

    nodeview2.AppendColumn("hello 0", new CellRendererText(), "text", 0).Clickable = true;
    nodeview2.AppendColumn("hello 1", new CellRendererText(), "text", 1).Clickable = true;
    nodeview2.AppendColumn("hello 2", new CellRendererText(), "text", 2).Clickable = true;
    nodeview2.AppendColumn("hello 3", new CellRendererText(), "text", 3).Clickable = true;

    // how to detect column header clicks:
    nodeview2.GetColumn(0).Clicked += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("HERE 0");
    nodeview2.GetColumn(1).Clicked += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("HERE 1");
    nodeview2.GetColumn(2).Clicked += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("HERE 2");
    nodeview2.GetColumn(3).Clicked += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("HERE 3");

    nodeview2.WidgetEvent += (s, e) =>
    {
        if ((e.Event is Gdk.EventButton ev) &&
           (ev.Type == Gdk.EventType.ButtonPress) &&
           (ev.Window == nodeview2.BinWindow))
        {
            if (nodeview2.GetPathAtPos((int)ev.X, (int)ev.Y, out var path, out var column))
            {
                // get the column index. There must be a better way?
                var columnIndex = nodeview2.Columns.Select(
                    (col, index) => new { col, index }).First(x => ReferenceEquals(x.col, column)).index;

                Console.WriteLine($"Clicked on column index {columnIndex} with title \"{column.Title}\"");

                var nodeValue = (MyTreeNode)_store.GetNode(path);
                Console.WriteLine($"Node selected: {nodeValue}");
            }
        }
    };

    nodeview2.ShowAll();
}
```

So the trick here is to catch the `EventButton`'s `ButtonPress` then take the coordinates and pass them to `GetPathAtPos()`. That returns column and path info. You can use that to derive what you need. I wish Gtk# was better documented/more widely used.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'll try to implement what you offer and report back.

Comment: Thanks again.  This resolved my problem.  I am now able to detect a click on a specific column in the NodeView.

Comment: @rrirower -- no problem. glad it worked out. If you have any other issues, i'd be more than happy to take a crack at them. Good luck!